# How do I express this query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) as an example to help me learn sqlalchemy.  Here is the mySQL:

```
select f.type, f.variety, f.price
from (
   select type, min(price) as minprice
   from fruits group by type
) as x inner join fruits as f on f.type = x.type and f.price = x.minprice;
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
s = Session()
sq = s.query(func.min(fruit.price)).group_by(fruit.type).subquery()
ans = s.query(fruit).join(sq, fruit.price==sq.c.price).all()
```

but it clearly does not work.  Am I even close?

I've been pouring over these [docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join).  `price` is a PK if that helps..  maybe i need an alias or something.  Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Following should do it:

Version when `fruit` is a `Table` instance:

```
q = (select([fruit.c.type, func.min(fruit.c.price).label("min_price")]).
    group_by(fruit.c.type)).alias("subq")

s = select([fruit], 
            and_(fruit.c.type == q.c.type,
                 fruit.c.price == q.c.min_price)
    )
res = session.execute(s)
```

Version when `fruit` is a `Model` type:

```
q = (select([fruit.type, func.min(fruit.price).label("min_price")]).
    group_by(fruit.type)).alias("subq")
s = (session.query(fruit).
        join(q, and_(fruit.type==q.c.type, fruit.price == q.c.min_price))
    )
res = s.all()
```

**Side note:** Float column as a PK does not sound like a great idea... and really, cannot two different fruits have the same price (which will violate uniqueness)?

Comment: Thank you.  Much obliged.  I'm getting a "fruit has no attribute c" error, so I think you meant `fruit.type`, not `fruit.c.type`, etc.  If not, I'd like to know what version of SA you are using.  (Regarding the side note, you are absolutely correct.  I'm intending to take what I learn here and apply it to a much more complicated query that selects the largest `fruit.id` which is indeed an int and the PK.)

Comment: I think that in my example `fruit` is a `Table` whereas in yours it probably is a model class. From your model class you can get a table by doing `fruit.__table__`.

Comment: @van: getting the table from a model class only works that way for declarative models;  The public interface is `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.manager_of_class(MAPPED_CLASS).mapper.mapped_table`, which will work on any mapped class no matter how they were defined.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Agree, this was the assumption though, which can be false.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure of this because I don't know what exception you're getting.

Since you're trying to get SQLAlchemy to execute a similar query to the one you posted, in which you have a `select` statement in your `from` clause, you'll need to call `mapper` on the result of a [`sqlalchemy.select`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-arbitrary-selects) similar to the linked example.  This mapped class will be your `x` in the query you're trying to imitate.  Then you can do `session.query(fruits).join((x, ...)).filter(...` to get the final result.

The `subquery` method of a query object, by contrast, is for situations where you desire [a `select` statement in the `where` clause](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries), as in  `where column in (select ...)`.  Use `subquery` to obtain what will become the **inner** select in the final generated query.  You can then create a separate (outer) query and join against the result of the `subquery` call.  To get SQLAlchemy to use a query similar to your example, it does not appear you will need to use this technique.

Comment: Is the use of a mapper over an alias preferential for any reason?

Comment: For the narrow case of your example, there is probably no advantage to using a `mapper` class instead of a `Table`, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This also works and is the syntax I am most familiar with.

```
s = Session()
sq = s.query(func.min(fruit.price).label('min_price').\
        group_by(fruit.type).subquery()
ans = s.query(fruit).join(sq, fruit.price==sq.c.min_price).all()
```

Comment: It works assuming the price is unique (which you mentioned is), but I am not sure why apples cannot cost same as oranges at some point of time. What I am trying to say: it would not work if there would be the same (minimum) price in more than one type.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534937/how-do-i-express-this-query-in-sqlalchemy/7552742#7552742 The prices are floats in the online example.  In my real-world case they are primary IDs